# Regular expression for Notepad++

Tags: html, regex, excel, html-table, notepad++

Long story short, I have a very large table (1200+ rows) from a custom Excel to html conversion, which is working beautifully, except for a final missing part. I'm no good with RegEx, and I think I need it for a Find and Replace in Notepad++. Below is what I have and what I need.

**Input:**

```
<td>image1</td>
<td>image2</td>
...
<td>image1242</td>
```

**Needed output:**

```
<td><img src="image1.png" alt="" /></td>
<td><img src="image2.png" alt="" /></td>
...
<td><img src="image1242.png" alt="" /></td>
```

Please advice!

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression:

```
<td>image(.+)</td>
```

and the following pattern as a replacement:

```
<td><img src="image\1.png" alt"" /></td>
```

As a sidenote, it is usually [not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) to parse HTML with regular expressions - in simple cases like this, it might be sufficient, but for anything more complicated, it would be much better to parse the HTML like XML file.

If you know some C#, you could use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for that.

Comment: @user1640453 I've edited the expression to accommodate for that - if there can be only numbers after the 'image', you could use `<td>image([0-9]+)</td>` as the expression to make it a bit safer.

Comment: Almost there, but missing the png extension

Comment: Awesome, you nailed it! Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

Do this way:-

### Find What:

```
<td>image(\d+)</td>
```

### Replace With:

```
<td><img src="image\1.png" alt="" /></td>
```

Refer the screenshot:

[image: Find Replace with Regex]